# Why doesn't my brugmansia flower

Tags: diagnosis, flowers

It looks healthy with lots of leaves and 2' tall but no flowers.  I kept it over the winter and it survived well.

Comment: More sun? Fertilize with a high middle number (10-15-10)?

Comment: Hi Susan, perhaps you post a picture